# using max power transfer theorem to calculate the value of the Rload

Tags: resistors

[image]

I am clueless of how to find the RL with Max power transfer theorem because don't you need RL to do the max power theorem? I've researched this for like 2 hours now help would be appreciated.

my understanding:
I=Vs/Rs+Rl
then you complete a table of current against power?

Comment: No you don't. The max power theorem tells you the value to use for RL.

Comment: Can you state the *maximum power transfer theorem* as you have learned it ? Please [edit] it into the question. The version you learned might be confusing.

Comment: Do you know how to find a Thevenin equivalent?

Comment: Michael, please respond to each and every one of these excellent thoughts and suggestions above. They are all there to help you with this. Help them do that.

Comment: I don't know how to find the Thevenin equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maximum Power Transfer theorem states:

*The load resistance that absorbs the maximum power from a two-terminal circuit is equal to the Thévenin resistance*

Do you know how to find the Thévenin resistance of a two-terminal circuit?

I'll give you a start. You have to find the equivalent resistance seen **when looking into the terminals** of your circuit, with \$R_L\$ taken out and your voltage source shorted.

[image]

Can you take it from here or do you need more help?

Comment: thanks for the help. Just to be sure youre saying that the Thevenin resistance = Rload? and if you are is the answer 13611.111

Comment: If you want Rload to absort the maximum power from the circuit, then yes \$R_t=R_L\$. If my answer helped you, you can show me by upvoting or accepting it as answer. @Michaelscott

Comment: I also get that \$R_L=R_t=13.6 \text{k}\Omega\$ - @Michaelscott